# MYSQL cumulative sum by date

Tags: mysql

How can i do cumulative sum?

My query is :

```
select dateb,ricetype,bajet1
from bajet
where ricetype='grand total'
```

How do i archieve 'New Value'?

[image: expected results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below :

```
set @CumSum := 0;
select dateb, ricetype, bajet1, (@CumSum := @CumSum + bajet1) as New_Value
from bajet where ricetype='grand total';
```

Comment: It works  great!Thanks a lot!